# Changing current address to another address

Tags: solidity, web3js, addresses, testrpc

I'm writing in Solidity using [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) and [truffle](https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle).

I wish to test my functions by altering my current address imitate other addresses.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
function getCurrAddress() constant returns(address currAddr){
    currAddr = msg.sender;
    return currAddr;
}

var accounts = web3.eth.accounts
contract.getCurrAddress() results in  = '0x53a1962e8844b2c9f1eed6e85e4d2026126ade0e'

web3.eth.defaultAccount = accounts[1]
      == '0xab6fa1d299e3b7d67fffd0829341534684d46560'

contract.getCurrAddress() results in  = '0x53a1962e8844b2c9f1eed6e85e4d2026126ade0e'
```

Is there a way I can change my current address as defaultAccount doesn't seem to be doing the job?

Answer (score 2):

You can just put your preferred address in the `from` field of the call.

i.e.

```
contract.getCurrAddress.call({from:"myAddress"});
```

Comment: Thanks Tjaden Hess! I had actually just read another question about this and it said from:"..." but i didn't know you could specify it in a method.  Thanks again.

Comment: To call a method that requires parameters:
`contract.function.call(parameters,{from:'myAddress'})`